# Querying between 2 values with a min and max

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The context is group discounts where a group of people between 4-7 would get a 5% discount and a group between 8-12 would get 10%. When I query with `5` people. I get `[]` back using the following query:

```
  await Discount.find({ amount: { $gte:5, $lte: 8 } })
    .then((discounts) => {
      console.log(discounts);
    })
    .catch(next);
```

But I was trying to get the following object:

```
[
  {
    name: '4+ Group Size',
    amount: 4,
  },
  {
    name: '8 Group Size',
    amount: 8,
  }
]
```

How do I query BETWEEN two values?

Comment: your query will return documents with `criteria` value greater or equal to 4 and less than or equal to 8

Comment: @nimrodserok yeah, I guess I should look for just `lte`, I just thought there was a way to query between a min and a max so `5` is less than the max of 8 but also matches the min of `gte 4`

Comment: There is a way to query between min and max and that is what you did. Your max is 8 and min is 4. Anything with a value between or equal to one of them will be matched.

Comment: so the document with `amount` 5 should return 2 docs? `4+ Group Size` and the `8 Group Size`? I am currently only seeing the `8 Group Size` one returning when I use `Discount.find({ amount: { $gte:6, $lte: 8 } })`

Comment: The query you mentioned will return document with `6<= amount <=8`, so `amount` 4 or 5 will not be returned

Comment: @nimrodserok yeah, that's what I am seeing. I am trying to basically say between 4-8 people gets a certain percentage, 8-12 get's a different one, etc... so min is 4 and max is 8, anything in between should give me the 4-8 objects. Any suggestion on what to do to achieve that?

Comment: The question is not clear. Can you provide sample documents, the input and requested results for them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255180/discussion-between-jeffci-and-nimrod-serok).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a db like this:

```
[
  {
    name: "0 Group Size",
    amountOfPeople: 0,
    discount: 0
  },
  {
    name: "4+ Group Size",
    amountOfPeople: 4,
    discount: 5
  },
  {
    name: "8 Group Size",
    amountOfPeople: 8,
    discount: 10
  }
]
```

You can use a query:

```
db.collection.find({ amountOfPeople: {$lte: numberOfPeopleInGroup}})
.sort({amountOfPeople: -1}).limit(1)
```

To get the relevant discount per amount of people in the group

See how the logic works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/U2Tf4tk1pfO) using aggregation pipeline only because of the playground limitations.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the $and operator

```
await Discount.find( { $and:[ {amount:{$gte:4}}, {amount:{$lte:8}} ] } )
  .then((discounts) => {
    console.log(discounts);
  })
  .catch(next);
```